# Weird Error with Encapsulated Nested Class

Tags: c#, class, encapsulation

I have A Class Called "BaseMember"

I've made it abstact.

The reason for this is, I have two classes that extend BaseMember that are nested inside of BaseMember

The one I'm focusing on right now is JuniorMember.

My Environment doesn't recognise JuniorMember as being a class, even though I've already made the class.

but for some reason it recognises "BaseMember.JuniorMember"

```
BaseMember.JuniorMember jmem2 = new BaseMember.JuniorMember("Andrew", "Adderson", "Bjorn", "Sir", "Hillclose", "Sweden", "zr13ny", "Adderson@hotmail.com",
            564312, 01698763122, 3, "Junior", "AA1299J", 0, 0, "none", "Swift Swe's", "Male", 2, 99, 1, 2, "dkane", "santa", "999292", "", "yes");
```

I know this code isn't correct. I have another Nested Class structure like this which involves BaseRace which has Sprint and Run classes encapsulated inside it, and that works as intended:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtE6m.png

I have a few questions:

1) How do I fix my JuniorMember class so that I can use "JuniorMember" without having to write BaseMember.

2)this is kinda a *bonus* question -- I have like, 25 parameters, do I really need to do stuff like this every time I make a new extending class constructor? it's unsightly.

```
  public Sprint(string rname, int rid, string rloc, string rtime, string rdist, string rclimb, string rdesc, string rimg, string rter,
                string rcon, string rdir, string rwin, int rrecord, string rrace, string rdate,string rdatec,string rcat,string rgen, string rdif, string rlim, string rcre)
                : base(rname,rid,rloc,rtime,rdist,rclimb,rdesc,rimg,rter,rcon,rdir,rwin,rrecord,rrace,rdate,rdatec,rcat,rgen,rdif,rlim,rcre)
            {
            nameRace = rname;


    RaceID = rid;

    }
```

Thanks guys.

By the way, this is for a project to do with Members (Junior and Senior) only being able to join Junior and Senior Races. The Classes kinda have to be nested for this, I don't really see the benefit of them either, but I have to use them.

Comment: Where is `JuniorMember` defined in relation to `BaseMember`? Is it defined inside `BaseMember` (nested)? If you don't need it there, just define it separately.

Comment: Show the class definition. It sounds like you have *nested* classes as opposed to classic inheritance.

Comment: The Class JuniorMember IS nested inside the BaseMember class, I kinda need it there I think.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum *Very rarely* do you actually *need* nested classes. In fact, its pretty much never. They may make sense for a given design, but you can always do it the other way

Comment: `I have like, 25 parameters, do I really need to do stuff like this every time I make a new extending class constructor` That ought to be a sign that you should think about your design a little more. Perhaps you need a class that wraps some (or all) of those pieces together so you can pass just a single object. Or maybe a smaller group of objects that wrap related pieces.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum: "I kinda need it there I think."   Why do you think that?  You can't solve your problem without changing it.

Comment: `I kinda need it there I think`, you probably don't. There are a few issues relating to scope and visibility (visibility being your actual problem here) that can be solved with nested classes, but that's probably not something you need here. Just move `JuniorMember` outside of `BaseMember`.

Comment: *need* more for my project more than anything else, I think I *need* to show how nested classes work.

It's not a personal project, if It was I totally would just move Junior to a separate non-nested class, since it improves readability.

Comment: If it must be nested, then you will just have to qualify the class name with `BaseMember.JuniorMember` when you refer to it outside of `BaseMember`.

Comment: @recursive like I've said, I have a BaseRace Class that also has Two nested Classes (Race and Sprint)

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum Just for the record, with everything you've said, the fact that anyone is *asking* you to do nested classes here is messed up. There is no benefit to using them from what I can see.

Comment: @MattBurland how can This be true when for BaseRace I can Call "Race" and "Sprint" just fine? http://imgur.com/zyh1cGs

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum: That can only be true if you're doing it inside the `BaseRace` class or if you are using type aliases or if `Race` actually refers to a different type. (like maybe in another namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote the class myself and turns out all I had was a syntax error somewhere.

works as intended now.